# mysql, update table in range of radius in lat, lng result from select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a database that I keep lat, lng,  so find solution to select routes in radius using this code

```
SELECT `id`, (3959 * acos( cos( radians(46.352165) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(6.096681) ) + sin( radians(46.352165) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) )
AS distance FROM`routes` HAVING distance < 1`
```

But now can't find solution to update one of the columns with the results  of select I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update routes :

```
UPDATE routes  JOIN
  (
    SELECT `id`, (3959 * acos( cos( radians(46.352165) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(6.096681) ) + sin( radians(46.352165) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) as distance from routes having distance <1
) as t2
ON (routes.id = t2.id)
SET varYouWantToSet=distance;
```

Your question confuse me a little, so forgive me if I am not answering correctly ^^'

Comment: I try to use your code  but get error,  "#1052 - Column 'crag_name' in field list is ambiguous "

code I use is:

UPDATE `routes`  JOIN
  (
    SELECT `id`,`crag_name`, (3959 * acos( cos( radians(46.352165) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(6.096681) ) + sin( radians(46.352165) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) as distance from `routes`  having distance <1
) as `t2`
ON (routes.id = t2.id)
SET `crag_name`="VESANCY";

Comment: You don't use your distance to set something there, is it normal ?
crag_name in field is ambiguous mean he found more than one declaration of it, have you tried putting `routes.crag_name` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE routes  
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT `id`, (3959 * acos( cos( radians(46.352165) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(6.096681) ) + sin( radians(46.352165) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS YOURUPDATEDVAL from routes having distance <1
) Z
ON (routes.id = Z.id)
SET routes.YOURUPDATECOLUMN=Z.YOURUPDATEDVAL;
```

As mention in above query ,you can try **`inner join`** which will made by Some sample table here it is **`Z`**.
And now you can update your column value using that value return by inner table or query.
Here i had mention that using SET **`routes.YOURUPDATECOLUMN=Z.YOURUPDATEDVAL`**.

Hope this will helps you.